why my npm package work with react an not on nextjs?
Hello I create a package and I test it with react. it's work but when I try on next I get an error : ReferenceError: exports is not defined.
I think it's an error in my config but I’m a beginner when it comes to npm packages so I don’t know how to do it.
This is my npm package: "thomasop-form": "^1.0.2",
And this is the code of my package : https://github.com/thomasop/npm_form (dev branch)
and I use it like this on react and next :
import { Container, Form, TextField } from "thomasop-form";
const [value, setValue] = useState();
return (
<>
  <Container>
    <Form
      method={"GET"}
      url={"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"}
      setValue={setValue}
    >
      <TextField name={"firstname"} required={true} regex={/^[0-9]$/} />
      <TextField name={"lastname"} />
    </Form>
  </Container>
</>
)

how to make it work on react and next ?
Thank you for your help

You built and publish as CJS but the nearest package.json defines type: module. ESM uses export. Try removing the type field from package.json, but that might have other ramifications for your DX.

I tried to make some changes but now even on react it doesn’t work anymore... and I can’t come back like before

@morganney I try different way but nothing work and I found nothing on web. Do you have an other solution? I follow this tutorial tuto
